# Adding a shower to this bathtub

Tags: water, shower, waterproofing, bathtub

I'm trying to add a shower option to this bathtub. I'm a very new home owner and don't even know if this is a good idea. The challenges I'm having are:

- Connecting a hand held shower head to the existing faucet and attaching a mount to the ceiling. A picture of the size and thread of the faucet aerator is below.
- Attaching a curtain rod that would surround the shower area. The dimensions of the entire tub area (wall to wall, and wall to edge) are 76x39 in. The tub itself and the ideal area enclosed by curtains is 54x35 in. I can't seem to find a D shaped curtain rod with those dimensions.
- Determining if the ceiling will be resistant enough to the moisture. It has two fresh coats of semi-gloss paint, but is only ~5 inches above the users head. You can see an opening where a venting fan and lightbulb are. It has a clear plastic cover that was removed for the picture. It allows air in from the sides so I can't see water bouncing in there, but I'm worried about the ceiling water resistance.

  1. What thread is that and where can I find shower hoses that will attach?
  2. What are my best options for fitting the 54x35 in. dimensions for a surrounding shower curtain.
  3. Is the ceiling going to have water problems? If so what can I do about it?
  4. Are there other problems I'm not seeing?

[image: Fitting]
[image: Bathtub]

Answer (score 1):

I have to comment that that tub structure is not really designed for a shower. You would have to install a shower curtain that draped into the tub on at least three sides to prevent water accumulation along the walls beyond the lip of the tub.

As a suggestion you could look into a shower kit designed to convert an old style free standing tub into a shower but personally I think it would really uglify your bath area.

[image]

Comment: I addressed this idea in my OP and commented on what the issue was with it.